# Как отследить деление на 0 в калькуляторе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот мой код:

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = input()
if c == "+":
    print(a + b)
elif c == "-":
    print(a - b)
elif c == "/":
    if b == "0":
        print("Деление на 0!")
    print(a / b)
elif c == "*":
    print(a * b)
elif c == "mod":
    if b == "0":
        print("Деление на 0!")
    print(a % b)
elif c == "pow":
    print(a ** b)
elif c == "div":
    if b == "0":
        print("Деление на 0!")
    print(a // b)
```

Я написал что если переменная c равняется нулю то пусть программа выведет мне, и условие в условии, но если b равняется 0 то выведи Деление на нол!, но не работает это, как это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

1. Проблема в том, что после того, как вы прописали `print` с предупреждением, вы не задали никаких последующих действий, т.е. программа всё равно делит на 0.
2. в `if` вы задали **0** тип `string`, хотя должен быть `float`. Уберите кавычки !

   ```
    elif c == "/":
        if b == 0:
            print("Деление на 0!")
        else:
            print(a / b)
   ```

---

```
a = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
b = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
c = input("Введите действе: ")

if c == "+":
    print(a + b)
elif c == "-":
    print(a - b)
elif c == "/":
     if b == 0:                     # +++ вместо  `if b == "0"`:
         print("Деление на 0!")
     else:
         print(a / b)
elif c == "*":
    print(a * b)
elif c == "mod":
    if b == 0:                      # +++ вместо  `if b == "0"`:
        print("Деление на 0!")
    else:                           # +++
        print(a % b)                # ---->
elif c == "pow":
    print(a ** b)
elif c == "div":
    if b == 0:
        print("Деление на 0!")      # +++ вместо  `if b == "0"`:
    else:                           # +++        
        print(a // b)               # ---->
```

Comment: Думаю следует еще написать про `ZeroDivisionError`